# ¿Es posible definir una función para la validación de una pregunta de un formulario de Google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

quiero poder validar campos de un google Form mediante funciones personales, es decir, que el setTextValidation de un campo ( o otra funcion) ejecuta una funcion definida por mi, aue indique si las respuesta es vàlida.
Estoy generando un google form desde apps script y quireo establecer validaciones de campo para:
NIF/NIE: podria validar la sintaxis del dato introducido con expresiones regulares pero no podria (o no se) como verificar que la letra introducida se corresponde con el numero. Tengo una funcion que me calcula la letra y verifica que se ha introducido la letra correcta. Pero no se como meterla para que google form la ejecute para validar el campo.

campos de texto: hacer que el valor introducido pase a mayúsculas.
Y algún campo más.

Alguien puede decirme si puedo hacer que google apps use estas funciones para validar los campos??

gràcies

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta necesita ser más específica, podrías enfocarla en cómo usar la validación de datos en el formulario de Google o bien en si es posible usar una función personalizada (te adelanto que lo segundo no es posible). Si deseas enfocar la pregunta en cómo usar la validación de datos del formulario de Google muestra lo que has intentado, preferentemente agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Gracias Rubén, efectivamente la pregunta esta poco clara. 
Pero aún así has resuelto mi duda. Lo que pretendia era saber si para la validacion de un valor introducido en GForm podia usar una función definida por mi. Sabiendo que no es posible no insisto en el tema. Me conformaré con usar Expresiones regulares que por otra parte tampoco he sabido encontrar como especificar la RegEx en el setValidation(). Preguntaré en https://es.stackoverflow.com que seguro que me hechan una mano.